# How to declare textbox as a global variable?

Tags: vb.net, module, global-variables

I have declared a textbox via button click:

```
Dim tp = TabControl2.TabPages(TabControl2.TabPages.Count - 1)
Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
txtbox.Location = New Point(200, 0)
txtbox.Height = 20
txtbox.Width = 100
tp.Controls.Add(txtbox)
```

Now I want a label in another sub to display the content of the textbox. My first attempt was:

```
label.Text = txtbox.text
```

But that didn't work because my textbox was declared locally and I have no idea how to declare this as a global variable...

Comment: Declare the textbox in a module and you are done! You dont need `Dim txtbox As New TextBox()`. Global variables are bad in large projects when finding new names start to become difficult or when you use threads. Otherwise it is fine.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε : It appears he is adding text boxes dynamically to the last tab page. Presumably he is also adding new tab pages dynamically, so a global variable wouldn't work very well unless it is _a list_ of text boxes.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to avoid global variables if there are workarounds for the task you have. For example you can retrieve your textbox from the Controls collection where you have added it. You just need something to help you locate the right textbox.

```
Dim tp = TabControl2.TabPages(TabControl2.TabPages.Count - 1)
Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
txtbox.Location = New Point(200, 0)
txtbox.Height = 20
txtbox.Width = 100
txtbox.Name = "MyImportantTextBox"
tp.Controls.Add(txtbox)
```

Now when you want to retrieve it

```
Dim tp = TabControl2.TabPages(TabControl2.TabPages.Count - 1)
Dim textbox = tp.Controls.
                 OfType(Of TextBox).
                 FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "MyImportantTextBox")
if textbox IsNot Nothing Then
    label.Text = textbox.Text
End If
```

There is also another simpler possibility, add an handler for the textbox TextChanged event and when you type something in that textbox reflect the content in the label.

```
Dim tp = TabControl2.TabPages(TabControl2.TabPages.Count - 1)
Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
txtbox.Location = New Point(200, 0)
txtbox.Height = 20
txtbox.Width = 100
AddHandler txtbox.TextChanged, AddressOf OnMyTextBoxChange
tp.Controls.Add(txtbox)
```

And add an event handler for the txtbox like this

```
Sub OnMyTextBoxChange(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim txtbox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    label.Text = txtbox.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you never set the text property.  Try this:

```
Dim tp = TabControl2.TabPages(TabControl2.TabPages.Count - 1)
Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
txtbox.Text = "Some Text"
txtbox.Location = New Point(200, 0)
txtbox.Height = 20
txtbox.Width = 100
tp.Controls.Add(txtbox)
```

I added one line of code to your example.

Comment: thx for ur fast response, but my lable-sub still doesnt find the before declared textbox

Comment: For a more complete answer, refer to the response from @Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan had a good idea.

My personal choice would be declaring a global string variable and during your button click procedure assigning it the value of your textbox.

Comment: What if he has many text boxes in many tab pages? Then a single variable wouldn't be enough. Better to follow Steve's suggestion and get exactly the one you want.